# Which is the POS port in the picture?

Tags: switch

Which is the POS port?

I read the [juniper-interface pos](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junose15.1/topics/reference/command-summary/interface-pos.html), there seems have no introduce of it.

I have a Juniper-EX4200 interfaces picture:

The front:
[image: The front]

The back:
[image]

There I do not find a interface named POS port, so, who can explain for me?

Comment: I really doubt an ethernet switch can do SONET.

Comment: the manual has the POS port configuration.

Comment: which manual would that be? I can understand if the *JunOS* manual has it (since some of the other platforms *do* support SONET), I really doubt the *EX* series (which is positioned as a datacenter switch) supports this, I don't see SONET, SDH or POS mentioned in the datasheet: https://www.juniper.net/assets/us/en/local/pdf/datasheets/1000215-en.pdf

Comment: I think should have a optical fiber convertor.

Comment: That has nothing to do with POS. The 'network ports' on the front can have fiber ports (SFP), depending on the exact model of EX4200 you have, as you can see on https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/reference/specifications/front-panel-ex4200.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pos`is a packet over SONET interface.

In the picture that you are attaching there is not a SONET interface, they look like this:

[image]

It's a fiber optics interface able to use SONET as signaling and `pos` is a definition that permits to transport packets over SONET.